# Wrap library with thunkify for co

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, koa, co

I was wondering how to thunkify (wrap in thunk) a library for use with co. The library is like the following. All the Client calls use other objects in the library.

```
Library.Client = function(opts) {
}

Library.Client.prototype.createList = function(opts, cb) {
  options.client = this;

  var list = new Library.List(opts, function(err, data) {
    if (typeof(cb) === 'function') {
      cb(err, list, data);
    }
  });
}

Library.List = function(opts, cb) {
  // setup with opts

  if (cb) this.fetch(cb);
}

Library.List.prototype.fetch = function(cb) {
  var list = [1,2];// get list
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i] = new Library.Item(list[i]);
  });
  if (typeof(cb) === 'function') cb(err, data);
}

Library.Item = function(opts) {
}

exports.client = Library.Client;
exports.list = Library.List;
exports.item = Library.Item;
```

Then you use the library like this.

```
var client = new Library.client(opts);
client.createList();
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a library that does what you want:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/thunkify-wrap